# Firebase Realtime Database Rules based on data not in query

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Given the following Firebase query:

```
listId = 'some dynamic value';
firebase.database().ref('myLists').orderByChild('id').equalTo(listId).on('value', (snapshot) => {
  // ...
})
```

And given the following database structure:

```
rootProject: {
  myLists: {
    <FirebaseGeneratedID>: {
      id: 'some dynamic value',
      isVisible: true
    }
  }
}
```

How can I control `.read` access to the database property, based on `isVisible`?